# Definition of finite maps

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\varphi:W\rightarrow V$ be a regular map of algebraic subsets of affine space $A_{k}^{n}$, $k$ algebraically closed. Then we have the following map between the co-ordinate ring of $V$ and $W$, $$\varphi^{*}:k[V]\rightarrow k[W] \\ 
                f\rightarrow f \circ \varphi   $$

$\varphi$ is finite if $k[W]$ is a finite $k[V]$-algebra. In this case, is $\varphi^{*}$ the structural homomorphism of the algebra? In other words, is there any role of $\varphi$ in making $k[W]$ a finite $k[V]$-algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $k[W]$ is to be considered as a $k[V]$-algebra via $\varphi^*$.  So $\varphi$ is defined to be a finite map if the map $\varphi^*$ makes $k[W]$ a finite $k[V]$-algebra.